# Is there a way to add a signature of version controll to PDF joboptions?

Tags: pdf

I'd like to create a method to check if my client used my specific joboptions to create a PDF.

Is there a way to add some sort of meta data or version data or signature to jobtions so that you get some sort of footprint when somebody uses these joboptions?

UPDATE:
The joboptions are created from the PDF-preset window in Adobe photoshop. The joboptions are send to the client with a manual on how to import these options and select them from their own PDF-preset window from any Adobe program.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility could be inserting according values to the metadata of the resulting PDF. There are entries for metadata in the joboptions file. However, an almost 4 years old entry in the [Adobe forums](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/786242?tstart=0) did not trigger any answers; you'd have to try things out, after getting familiar with the joboptions syntax.

You may also have to be aware that joboptions are only used in Distiller. If your user uses another way to create the PDF (such as the "modern" way exporting a PDF directly out of the application, using the Adobe library), your joboptions would not be honored.

If metadata does not work out, you might assemble a Preflight Profile testing for the features you need, and run this profile on the files you get from your users. In this case, it is not your joboptions which are important, but whether the result is compliant to your requirements. You may also consider creating a Preflight Droplet using the Preflight Profile, which then would filter out the non-compliant files.

Comment: The are provided to the client with a manual on how to load them in to their preferred adobe program. So they are able to choose the Adobe PDF-preset from their preferred program.
I'm unable to find anywhere how I can add Metadata manualy. I did find the values MetadataAuthor () -Keywords () -Subject () and MetadataTitle () in the joboptions file. I have no idea what values I can edit in here though.

Comment: These four items should have string values. So, you should be able to add any kind of text strings. However, it could be that Distiller does not really honor them. If you have a controlled environment (where you could set up workflows at your specs), there would be some other possibilities – mainly to set the metadate either using (Acrobat) JavaScript, or importing an XMP data set.

Comment: The values are empty in my joboptions. If I try to fill them with values, tried with quotes and without, and use these joboptions, they are nowhere to be found in the generated PDF. So I assume these are used in a different way, but I can't find any documentation on them.

Comment: If the mechanism works, you should find the values in the Document Properties. But, as the OP in the mentioned User-to-User forum says, it may not work as such.

Comment: I guess it does not work as such then. I also posted on the adobe support forums but they remain silent.
I find it rather hard to believe that so few people seem to have this problem. Seems like a frequent issue that you wish to check if a client used your specific joboptions =(.